# Algolia partialUpdateObject not working in Express app (React frontend)

Tags: node.js, express, prisma, algolia

**EDITED to add edited code with error message.**

I’m super new to Algolia, and I’m having an issue with the partialUpdateObject function. My app uses Prisma database, and everything updates there as expected. I’m also having no issues on the frontend, which is React if that’s helpful. My backend is Express. I apologize in advance for this cluster of a code block. I’ve tried so many variations of this that I’m out of ideas. I also tried—word for word—the example code that Algolia provides. Also, I’m able to sync up Algolia when I create a new record.

Within my Algolia dashboard, each record contains an Algolia-assigned objectID. When I console.log my object, the object comes back as undefined.

My code is really long because it contains the code to update Prisma as well, so I’ll first add the code with Prisma, followed by just the Algolia code, and then the error message. I very much appreciate any help! I'm 99% sure the rest of my function isn't structured properly either (still getting familiar with async and promises).

**With Prisma Update**

```
const updateSandbox = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    street,
    city,
    state,
    zip,
    phone,
    interests,
  } = req.body;

  const sandbox = await prisma.sandbox.update({
    where: {
      id,
    },
    data: {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      street,
      city,
      state,
      zip,
      phone,
      interests,
    },
  });

  res.status(200).json({ sandbox });

  const api_sandbox = {
    firstName: sandbox.firstName,
    lastName: sandbox.lastName,
    email: sandbox.email,
    street: sandbox.street,
    city: sandbox.city,
    state: sandbox.state,
    zip: sandbox.zip,
    phone: sandbox.phone,
    interests: sandbox.interests,
    id: sandbox.id,
    objectID: sandbox.objectID,
  };

  index
    .partialUpdateObject(api_sandbox, {
      createIfNotExists: true,
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

**Algolia Code Only**

````
    ```
    const api_sandbox = {
        firstName: sandbox.firstName,
        lastName: sandbox.lastName,
        email: sandbox.email,
        street: sandbox.street,
        city: sandbox.city,
        state: sandbox.state,
        zip: sandbox.zip,
        phone: sandbox.phone,
        interests: sandbox.interests,
        id: sandbox.id,
        objectID: sandbox.objectID,
      };
    
      index
        .partialUpdateObject(api_sandbox, {
          createIfNotExists: true,
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });

```
````

**Error Message**

> 

```
{
name: 'ApiError',
   message: "The 'objectID' attribute is required to use action=partialUpdateObject near line:1 column:270",
   status: 400,
   transporterStackTrace: [
     {
       request: [Object],
       response: [Object],
       host: [Object],
       triesLeft: 3
     }
   ]
 }
```

Thank you again for any help. I'm still learning and experimenting, so thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: is objectID undefined or something. have you tried refreshing the algolia dashboard to see if its a delay

Comment: @cmgchess Thanks for your response! I edited my post above because I edited my code and finally got an error message. But—to answer your questions, objectID is showing as undefined when I `console.log`, but in my Algolia dashboard, every record has an objectID—also not a delay with the dashboard.

Comment: the objectID is the unique identifier for each record on algolia end. perhaps you could use the `sandbox.id` (if thats undefined of course) as the objectID ?

Comment: @cmgchess Unfortunately the sandbox.id didn't work—still getting that same error message

Comment: are you looking to update an already existing record. if so can you go to the algolia dashboard and see what the objectID of that record is. does the objectID make any sense in that record (or a randomly generated one)

Comment: what i recommend when saving objects to algolia is to have an objectID that can be later referred so that updating is easy

Comment: @cmgchess I figured it out thanks to you! I didn't assign the objectID to the sandbox.id correctly—once I did, it worked! Thanks so much—I will post the updated code as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

With help from the comments on this post, I was able to figure it out! I'm not sure why the objectID was coming in as undefined, but instead, I didn't use Algolia's auto-generated objectID. I assigned the sandbox.id as the objectID. Worked like a charm. I noticed on Algolia's site that they don't recommend using their auto-generated objectIDs—so maybe this is why. Here is my code for reference (just the Algolia part):

```
const api_sandbox = {
      firstName: sandbox.firstName,
      lastName: sandbox.lastName,
      email: sandbox.email,
      street: sandbox.street,
      city: sandbox.city,
      state: sandbox.state,
      zip: sandbox.zip,
      phone: sandbox.phone,
      interests: sandbox.interests,
      objectID: sandbox.id,
    };

    index
      .partialUpdateObject(api_sandbox, {
        createIfNotExists: true,
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    console.log(api_sandbox)
```